# How to check the Recently executed TWS job stream

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

How can I check the TWS recently executed job stream

Is there any command to check when was jobstream/job last executed in last 365 days

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to query the [JOB_HISTORY_V](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_8.6.0.1/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_8.6.0.1/eqqr1jhistoryv.htm) view on the database.

There are also historical reports from DWC that work with data from that view.

Comment: Thankyou very much Franco for the answer
I got Command for Recently executed job streams (date and time)

rep7 -c Workstation Name -s Job Stream Name -f yyyymmdd -t yyyymmdd
where -f - from date , -t - till this date

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/TWS/SC32-1274-02/en_US/HTML/SRF_mst212.htm